# Regarding sites with a login option, should i have one/multiple navbar(s)?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've been fiddling with bootstrap navbars for a week or so.

Example navbars have: Brand, some links, a simple dropdown menu, & sign up/login buttons on the right.

What I've been wondering is... when someone *logs into the site*, should I have a separate navbar for "post-login" pages OR have the one navbar that ~changes~ in response to whether the user is signed in or not? What is the typical approach?

Fifteen minutes of googling and browsing questions on StackOverflow was fruitless. It seems as though I might be asking a silly question but I'm not sure - can someone clear this up for me?

Thank you for your time/help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Change navbar in bootstrap if user login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27209274/change-navbar-in-bootstrap-if-user-login)

After asking the question and doing some more research while I waited for an answer, 10 mins later I found that this^ SO question above likely holds my answer.

Thanks for all your help! :P